# How to make my clock app work

Tags: c

I wanted to make a timer that ran on user input like most timer apps or an egg timer.I wrote the code but I come up with garbage values and barely working code. Please help!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main(){
    int h=0;
    int s=0;
    int m=0;
    printf("Please enter the time you want for the timer.");
    printf("Please enter how many hours you want for the timer.(max 24!)");
    scanf("%d",&h);
    printf("Please enter how many minutes you want for the timer.(max 59!)");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("Please enter how many seconds you want for the timer.(max 59!)");
    scanf("%d",&s);

    while (s<=60){

        printf(" %d hours %d minutes and %d seconds \n", m ,s);//gives the     countdown output
        sleep(1); //for delaying in seconds.
        s++;// adds one to the second counter

        if(s==60){
        m++;//adds one to the second counter when seconds reach 60
        s=0;//resets seconds value to 0.
    }
        if(m==60){
        h++;
        m=0;
    }
        if(h==24){
        printf("The timer has reached Max output!\n");
        break;
        }
     }



     getch();
  }
```

Comment: Do debugging. Note that the loop condition `s<=60` won't be true after entering the loop because when `s==60` becomes true, `s` is set to `0`.

Comment: You invoked *undefined behavior* by not giving enough arguments for format specifier to `printf()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major problem is in

```
 printf(" %d hours %d minutes and %d seconds \n", m ,s);
```

here, you have supplied three format specifiers to `printf()`, but you pass only two arguments!! This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1, *`fprintf()`*

> The `fprintf` function writes output to the stream pointed to by `stream`, under control
>   of the string pointed to by `format` that specifies how subsequent arguments are
>   converted for output. **If there are insufficient arguments for the `format`, the behavior is
>   undefined.**

That being said, I think you should re-design the approach. This is supposed to be a *countdown* timer, so start with the given values, and try reaching zero for all the variables. There should be *decrements*, not *increments*.

Also, don't *expect* users to abide by the *on-screen instructions* (like `> (max 59!)`), validate the input yourself. Don't forget to check the return value of `scanf()`, too.

Answer (score 0):

Now while I know that this isn't the perfect answer. This is what I could come up with that works "close" to what I wanted. Thanks to everyone that helped. Here's what I came up with: (NOTE: while this is not strictly a countdown app!)
I hope to hear more critiques from you people! Thanks again!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main(){
    int input;
    int s=0;
    int m=0;


    printf("Please enter how many minutes you want for the timer.");
    scanf("%d",&input);

    while (s<=60){
        /*no need for fflush if you have new line*/
        printf("%d minutes and %d seconds \n",m ,s);//gives the countdown output
        sleep(1); //for delaying in seconds.
        s++;// adds one to the second counter

        if(s==60){
        m++;//adds one to the second counter when seconds reach 60
        s=0;//resets seconds value to 0.
    }

        if(m==input){
        printf("The timer has reached Max output!\n");
        break;
        }
    }



        getch();
}
```